# using makefile variable in sed command

Tags: bash, sed, makefile

I have tried putting the following command in makefile.

```
#get Local Ip Address
LOCALIP=$(shell ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{print $1}') &

#get Web Url from User
@read -p "Enter Web Url:" weburl; \

sed -e "\|$LOCALIP $weburl|h; \${x;s|$LOCALIP $weburl||;{g;t};a\\" -e "$LOCALIP $weburl" -e "}" hosts.txt
```

When I try to execute the command, I expected to get the sed command like following:

```
sed -e "\|192.168.5.1 www.weburl.com|h; \${x;s|192.168.5.1 www.weburl.com||;{g;t};a\\" -e "192.168.5.1 www.weburl.com" -e "}" hosts.txt
```

But, I get the following,

```
sed -e "\|/s/$/OCALIP eburl|h; \" hosts.txt
```

Comment: Makefile variables are usually enclosed in `$(...)`.

Comment: I tried. Now I am getting the following.
sed -e "\|192.168.5.1 & |h; \" hosts.txt

Comment: Instead of trying to convert all these shell statements to Makefile syntax, can't you put them into a script and call that script from the Makefile?

Comment: @oliv That's what I thought too.

Answer (score 0):

In Makefiles, variables longer than a single character (i.e. all variables that you're likely to define) needs to be expanded with `${varname}`, not `$varname`. The latter would result in the value of `$v` concatenated with the string `arname`, as you discovered.

I won't start to parse the rest of that Makefile as the piping looks a bit questionable.

Comment: Doesn't makefile use `$(varname)`, not `${varname}`?

Comment: @Barmar Both works. GNU Make says "either ‘`$(foo)`’ or ‘`${foo}`’ is a valid reference to the variable `foo`", and BSD Make uses `${foo}` exclusively in the manual.

Comment: I think parentheses are more idiomatic these days, and the [O'Reilly Make book](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/ch03.pdf) agrees.

Comment: @Bramar As with all thing concerning taste and style, use the conventions of the system or project you are working with. I'm personally a BSD guy, maintaining a couple of packages for one of the BSDs and submitting patches for packages in another (a "package" being essentially a Makefile on BSD). BSD Makefiles, for example in the `pkgsrc` package system from NetBSD or any Makefile in `/usr/src` on an OpenBSD system, uses curlies, only, so I use them too. Makes it easier if you are a shell programmer too, as the different conventions have very different semantics in Makefiles and in the shell.